# I need to cut off input dropdown background color transparent

Tags: html, css, cut

```css
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(
    11% -16%,
    circle closest-corner,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 96px,
    #efefef 74px,
    #fff    48px
);
```

this is my current code. I want to cut off this dropdown , cut off this bg should be transparent.

[image]

Comment: You don't need the `-webkit-` prefix. It's been unnecessary for almost a decade now.

Comment: Also, `<input>` elements aren't "dropdowns" - that's a `<select>` element - and they're almost impossible to style consistently across browsers and devices.

Comment: The post need more info, provide an example or a demo

Comment: I edited your post to fix your broken image link. It looks like your "dropdown" is a just a normal `<div>` that's separate from your `<input />` and is managed by some auto-complete script? In which case you need to post your full rendered HTML and JS so we can reproduce the layout issue - until and unless you do that we cannot really help you.

Comment: It's not a <select> element . it's just a normal <div> , and managed by some auto-complete script. I need to make this input filled transparent and need to cut this dropdown same as given picture,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make dropdown list you must have to use  element as  tag is used for text, email, tel, button, date, etc.

For this use "background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1));

output will be transparent from left side and if you wants transparent at right side as well use rgba (255,0,0,0) also you can do the same for middle part as well.

Thanks.